# Show that: $nf(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n})+n\left(\frac{f(M)+f(m)}{2}-f(\frac{M+m}{2})\right) \ge f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)$

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

I am looking for a proof of the problem as following:

Let $f(x)$ is a real continuous function that is strictly convex ($f''>0$) on $[m, M]$, let $m \le x_i \le M$, for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$ then show that:

$$nf\left(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{n}\right)+n\left(\frac{f(M)+f(m)}{2}-f\left(\frac{M+m}{2}\right)\right) \ge f(x_1)+\cdots+f(x_n)$$

Equality holds if only if $m=x_1=x_2=\cdots=x_n=M$

Comment: `Equality holds if [and] only if ...` The `only if` part can't be true. Equality trivially holds for a constant function no matter what $m, M, x_i$ for example.

Comment: @dxiv The function that is convex, so the function is not a constant function

Comment: A constant function *is* convex (and concave, for that matter). I guess what you have in mind is a **strictly** convex function, see the definitions at [mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConvexFunction.html) or [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function) for example. If you do mean a *strictly* convex function then you should edit the question and spell it out.

Comment: Your edit `f'' > 0` introduces the assumption that the function would have a 2nd order derivative, which is a far stronger assumption than the original one of continuity. Why not simply call it for what it is - a `*strictly* convex function` - and leave derivatives out of the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inequality does not hold in general. For a simple counterexample, consider the convex function:

$$
  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
0  & \text{if $x \lt \frac{2}{3}$} \\
x - \frac{2}{3} & \text{if $x \ge \frac{2}{3}$}
\end{cases}
$$

and $m=0, M=1, n=3, x_1=0, x_2=x_3=1$.

Since $f(0)=f(\frac{1}{2})=f(\frac{2}{3})=0, f(1)=\frac{1}{3}$ the inequality becomes:

$$
3 f(\frac{2}{3}) + 3(\frac{f(0)+f(1)}{2} - f(\frac{1}{2})) \ge f(0) + 2 f(1)
$$
$$
\frac{1}{2} \ge \frac{2}{3}
$$
where the latter is obviously false.

For a counterexample using a *strictly* convex function, one can choose $f(x) = e^x$, $m = 0 \le M$, $n=3$, $x_1=0, x_2=x_3=M$. The inequality becomes:

$$
3 e^{\frac{2}{3}M} + 3(\frac{1+e^M}{2} - e^\frac{M}{2}) \ge 1 + 2 e^M
$$

$$
- \frac{1}{2} e^M + 3 e^{\frac{2}{3}M} - 3 e^\frac{M}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \ge 0
$$

The latter will fail for large enough $M$ since the dominant term $e^M$ has a negative coefficient.

Comment: Dear Mister @dxiv, Thank to You, see here http://mathoverflow.net/questions/247930/inspire-from-kantorovich-inequality

Comment: @OaiThanhĐào Thank you for the followup. The new formulation posted at MO looks right, indeed.